# WordPress: How to display the results for "0" in search field

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm setting following if statement to display the message "Please enter the words." when users input nothing in the field.
The reason for this setting is to avoid WordPress showing all the posts as results when search field is empty.

```
<?php if(isset($s) && empty($s)): ?>

<p>Please enter the words.</p>

<?php else: ?>

//Search results loop

<?php endif; ?>
```

It's almost working well but when you input "0", it turns the "false" and shows the message.
I understand that it's something natural in PHP, but is there any way to show the results for "0" instead?

I want to display the posts that include the word "0" as it's result.

like...
"10-year-old girl"
"0%"

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove empty() from if condition and change it to:

```
if(isset($s))
```

because empty() method return boolean true for '0' (string) also, but isset will return true as $s is set with value '0' (string). So net if condition turns to false. 
After removing empty() it will return if condition as true and will return results.